# Its possible to use AWS Athena using a VPC endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

I would like to know if it is possible to create a VPC endpoint for AWS Athena and restrict to only allow certain users (that MUST BE in my account) to use the VPC endpoint. I currently use this VPC endpoint policy for a S3 endpoint and I would need something similar to use with AWS Athena.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<MY_ACCOUNT_ID>:user/user1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<MY_ACCOUNT_ID>:user/user2",
                    ...
                ]
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is to block developers in my company, that are logged in a RDP session inside my company VPN, to offload data to a personal AWS account. So I would need a solution that blocks access to the public internet, so I think a VPC endpoint should be the only option, but I accept new ideas.

Comment: VPC endpoints are not supported with Athena. Are you not able to restrict access to the relevant resources using IAM policies per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/access.html?

Comment: With IAM policies is not possible because if I allow the public AWS Athena endpoint (athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com for example) inside my private VPC, some developer in my company will be allowed to create a personal AWS account and will be able to offload data to his personal AWS account.

Comment: You need credentials to access these resources. How does this developer get credentials to access Athena and the underlying S3 data? If he does have credentials then he is allowed to access the data. Stopping someone with valid credentials from exfiltrating data is not a trivial task.

Comment: The developers access the private VPC throw a RDP session that blocks Copy/Paste (is a Windows GPO Policy), so the data remains inside the private VPC, the developers can only see the data, not extract or offload to their machines. They can only access S3 inside this environment using the S3 endpoint. If they create a personal AWS account they will not be able to offload the data to a personal S3 bucket they created because they can only access the endpoint using credentials from my company account. So that is why I need a endpoint policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, check out this doc.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/interface-vpc-endpoint.html

Also, keep in mind to adopt a encryption at rest and transit when query data via athena, the results always by default is open even if it's saved on a encrypted s3 bucket.